# Is the source for gluon's netbeans project templates (Gluon-Glisten-Afterburner, Gluon-Multiview-FXML, Gluon-Multiview) available?

Tags: java, templates, netbeans, gluon

Being a noob with **JavaFX**, and having fallen in love with *Gluon*'s 4 Netbeans project templates, I hope to make some minor changes.  However, there are no avenues for making slight modifications to the templates.

For example, all 4 of the templates generate a maven pom file with Java version 11 hardcoded.  I'd like to change that to 17 as it is tedious to manually change the pom file each time I use one of the plugins.

If the source were available, I could make that change (and others), and re-install locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can the source code for the templates used by the Gluon IDE plugins here:

https://github.com/gluonhq/ide-plugin-templates

And you can find the Gluon IDE plugins source code here:

https://github.com/gluonhq/ide-plugins

```
Gluon integration with Java IDEs. The repository contains Gluon plugin source for the following IDEs:

Eclipse
IntelliJ IDEA
Apache Netbeans
```

Related docs: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_ide_plugins

You can do changes and test locally, of course, but being an open source project, issues and pull requests are welcome.

Comment: Thanks for steering me back on course.  The first URL is broken.

Comment: @TheGeeko61 thanks for pointing it out. Now it is fixed.